# [ROS2] Finding the executable and source code for a node

Tags: ros2, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write an AppArmor profile for a ROS2 node, specifically, `/cartographer_node`, which was included in one of the packages for TurtleBot3 ROS2 (can be installed in this tutorial [here](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2/#setup)).

However, I am having trouble finding the specific file that the node is executed from. In fact, I am also having trouble finding the source code. Is it possible for someone with experience in playing around with TurtleBot3 ROS2 to help me locate the file? Thank you so much.

If not, would someone help me find the executable for any of the demo nodes? I could perhaps work my way from there.

**Edit:** I found the symbolic link to the executable in `~/<TURTLEBOT3 WORKSPACE>/install/cartographer_ros/lib/cartographer_ros`, and from there I found the actual executable in the build folder. However I still couldn't find the source code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324516/%5Bros2%5D-finding-the-executable-and-source-code-for-a-node/) by [wan_da](https://answers.ros.org/users/41699/wan_da/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2019-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you know which package the binary is hosted in *and* the package has been released through the ROS buildfarm, you can use [index.ros.org](https://index.ros.org) to search for it.

See [index.ros.org/p/cartographer_ros](https://index.ros.org/p/cartographer_ros/github-ros2-cartographer_ros/#crystal) for the page showing the Crystal version.

On that page there is a link to the source repository called *Checkout URI* in the *Repository Summary* section of the page (right under the *Package Summary* section on the left of the page).

For `cartographer_ros` that shows [ros2/cartographer_ros.git](https://github.com/ros2/cartographer_ros.git) for me.

Following that link -- and changing to the `crystal` branch -- leads me to the source code for all nodes in that package [here](https://github.com/ros2/cartographer_ros/tree/d4c62f7bf43dba1c4db582b47aa017b6fd7633b1/cartographer_ros).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wan_da](https://answers.ros.org/users/41699/wan_da/) on 2019-06-03**:
Oh, so it *is* that folder. Thank you very much.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-04**:
It is which folder?